# How to get Video Thumbnail saved within MediaStore.Downloads collection. Android Q

Tags: android, download, thumbnails, mediastore, android-10.0

friends.
I can't receive Bitmap by using ContentResolver#loadThumbnail(Uri, Size, CancellationSignal) for Video file, saved to Downloads collection. There is FileNotFoundException is thrown.

How I'm creating file in Downloads directory.

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    cv.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, mime);
    cv.put(MediaStore.Downloads.IS_PENDING, 1);
    Uri newFileUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
    //Writing file by streams here to "newFileUri".
    cv.clear();
    cv.put(MediaStore.Downloads.IS_PENDING, 0);
    context.getContentResolver().update(cv, cv, null, null);
```

Result: newFileUri="content://media/external/downloads/25"

When I'm trying to get Thumbnail Bitmap for this video file by:

```
context.getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(newFileUri, new Size(96, 96), null)
```

FileNotFoundException is thrown.

Please, give any advice how I can use #loadThumbnail method for this case.

Comment: I believe you should call `loadThumbnail` with `newFileUri` that is generated with `MediaStore.Video`. Even if it exists in `MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. Try calling it with `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`